# About the change of variables theorem in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres. Is $g$ a diffeomorphism of class $C^1$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> If $A$ and $B$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if $g:A\to B$ is a one-to-one function carrying $A$ onto $B$ such that both $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are of class $C^r$, then $g$ is called a **diffeomorphism** (of class $C^r$).

> **Theorem 17.2 (Change of variables theorem).** Let $g:A\to B$ be a diffeomorphism of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f:B\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then $f$ is integrable over $B$ if and only if the function $(f\circ g)|\det Dg|$ is integrable over $A$; in this case, $$\int_B f=\int_A (f\circ g)|\det Dg|.$$

In the statement of Theorem 17.2, $g$ is a diffeomorphism (of class $C^r$).
But the author didn't write the value of $r$.
What is the value of $r$?
Is $r$ equal to $1$?
I read Wikipedia about the change of variables theorem.
$r$ was $1$ in Wikipedia.

Comment: If $r$ is unspecified it usually means $1$-or-better

Comment: @FShrike Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: By the way, you can, using the inverse function theorem, manage with different hypotheses - continuously differentiable + nonzero derivative - and even that can be strengthened using Sard’s theorem. I don’t understand Sard’s theorem, but I think, essentially, it means you can get away with the derivative being zero in a few places since those points will form a measure zero set and thus not affect the integral. It might mean you have to partition the domain of integration into pieces where $g$ is invertible, though.

Comment: @FShrike Thank you very much for the information.